# Multiple publish configuration with ClickOnce

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I have a Winform project published with ClickOnce. However I need deploy this project in two sites with specific configurations (custom app.config changes). I have a RELEASE and a QA configurations but the Winform project allows a single publish configuration. Is there a way to make a publish configuration based on profile like in the Web projects and also applay a app.RELEASE.config transform?

Comment: [Building ClickOnce Applications from the Command Line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx)

Comment: As an example, you can publish from command-line this way: `msbuild "d:\project1\project1.csproj" /target:publish /property:PublishDir=d:\Publish\ /property:ApplicationVersion=1.0.0.0` and then increase the version or revision for the next time. You also can make a versioning strategy based on date or even keep the version somewhere and increase it.